# I can't save a drawn image

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, save, draw

I have a drawingView of type UIView where I can draw pictures. But this method save just I white area without my drawn picture. Why?

```
-(void)saveCurrentScreenToPhotoAlbum 
{    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingView.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [drawingView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: if you want to save draw image take the screen shot of this area and save it.

Comment: That's not really helpful; there are plenty of cases where an application might want to save the contents of the screen without requiring the user to take a screenshot manually. Plus a lot of iPhone users probably don't know how, as it's not an obvious feature.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, try moving

```
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

to the bottom of the function, after you save the image. Aside from that it looks the same as the code I used. If that doesn't work, can you provide a few more details on how/when you're calling this method, and what you're drawing to the screen?